# Raw_input & If Statements

Tags: python-2.7, variables, if-statement, dictionary, raw-input

I am trying to make a personal assistant for python named "Sansa".
I am a noob and I want my code to execute my initial_request variable only if users raw_input is yes. If it is no I want the code to execute the last engine.say command. I tried to achieve this using a dictionary. Thanks and sorry for the messy code.

```
import webbrowser
import pyttsx

#adding voice (i will change)
engine = pyttsx.init()
engine = pyttsx.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
for voice in voices:
   engine.setProperty('voice', voice.id)
#Introducing Sansa and trying to navigate through the codes. 
#serviceP =input
first_answer = {'pos' : 'Yes', 'neg' : 'No'}
response = engine.say("Hello my Lord. My name is Sansa and I am your personal assistant. I am here to serve you. Can I be of service?")
engine.runAndWait()
st = raw_input("Hello my Lord. My name is Sansa and I am your personal assistant. I am here to serve you. Can I be of service?")
initial_Request =('What would you like to do? I can visit various websites, perform a google or youtube search, and so much more.')

#evaluate yes or no to execute initial_Request
if st == first_answer['pos']:
engine.say(initial_Request)
engine.runAndWait()

elif st == first_answer['neg']:
    engine.say("Ok. I'm here if you need me.")
    engine.runAndWait()
```

Comment: I think you just have an indentation error for the two lines after the `if st == first_answer['pos']:` line. Since this is not indented it is not in the if statement and will instead run every time

Comment: That doesn't seem to fix it. When I run the code if I answer yes or no to the raw_input it doesn't execute the if statement or elif statement.  This is the output

Comment: Python 2.7.12 (default, Jul  1 2016, 15:12:24) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
=============== RESTART: /home/master/Desktop/Sansa_/Sansa.py ===============
Hello my Lord. My name is Sansa and I am your personal assistant. I am here to serve you. Can I be of service?yes
>>> 
=============== RESTART: /home/master/Desktop/Sansa_/Sansa.py ===============
Hello my Lord. My name is Sansa and I am your personal assistant. I am here to serve you. Can I be of service?no
>>>

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have found the problem to make the program run through the code such as adding the variable unknownResponse, adding print statements under the engine.say() functions,etc. However I am still working through a few bugs such as the voice not properly continuing throughout the if and elif statements. The program is coming together though. Here is the updated code.

```
import webbrowser
import pyttsx

#adding voice (i will change)
engine = pyttsx.init()
engine = pyttsx.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
for voice in voices:
   engine.setProperty('voice', voice.id)
   #Introducing Sansa and trying to navigate through the codes. Might need some type of loop to redirect the user

first_answer = {'pos' : 'Yes', 'neg' : 'No'}
engine.say("Hello my Lord. My name is Sansa and I am your personal   assistant. I am here to serve you. Can I be of service?")
engine.runAndWait()
st = raw_input("Hello my Lord. My name is Sansa and I am your personal   assistant. I am here to serve you. Can I be of service?")
initial_Request =("What would you like to do? I can visit various websites, perform a google or youtube search, and so much more.")
negative_Response =("Okay Master. I'm here if you change your mind.")
#evaluate yes or no to execute initial_Request
if st == first_answer['pos']:
    engine.say("What would you like to do? I can visit various websites, perform a google or youtube search, and so much more.")
    engine.runAndWait()
    print initial_Request

elif st == first_answer['neg']:
    engine.say("Okay Master. I'm here if you change your mind.")
    engine.runAndWait()
    print negative_Response
#add loop to make questions repeat

unknownResponse = True
while unknownResponse:
    againTry =raw_input("Sorry I don't understand. Please try again.")
    if st != first_answer['pos', 'neg']:
        engine.say("Sorry I don't understand. Please try again.")
        engine.runAndWait()
    unknownResponse = False
```